# How to make a SQL Server SUM return null if the summed values are all null

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column numeric. The column can have null values. I need to `SUM` all values but if all values are `NULL`, it should return `NULL`, but if at least one value is not null, it should return the sum.

Is there such a function? Select Func?(Column) From Table?

- NULL + NULL => NULL (I really need this to be NULL and not 0)
- 0 + NULL => 0
- 0 + 0 => 0

Comment: `SUM` works this way out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The `SUM` of `NULL` is `NULL`:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(int,C1) AS C1, C2, C3
    FROM (VALUES(NULL, NULL, 0),
                (NULL, 0, 0)) V (C1, C2, C3))
SELECT SUM(C1),
       SUM(C2),
       SUM(C3)
FROM VTE;
```

This returns the values `NULL`, `0`, and `0`, respectively.